# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2764800 into shape (1,1,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, opencv

The results of the print statements

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 ...

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]
([0], [1], [2])
<class 'tuple'>
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 ...

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]
<class 'list'>
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1, 1, 1]
720
```

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trial2\trial.py", line 63, in <module>
    image_stack(image)
  File "C:\Users\trial2\trial.py", line 52, in image_stack
    final_shape = transposed_axes.reshape(new_arr_shape)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2764800 into shape (1,1,1)
```

This function calculates the transpose axes values depending on the length of the of the `img.shape` array. Then it applies the transpose axes to the image and, also the new shape for the array is calculated using the `axes` variable. I'm having an issue in reshaping the transposed array with the `new_arr_shape`. As I keep getting the error being unable to reshape the array of size 276800 into shape (1,1,1). I don't understand how the array's size is 276800, and is there any way that I can fix that?
UPDATE: fixed the issue with the size of the array and now the issue is solved

```
import os
import numpy as np
import platform
import cv2

def image_stack(image):
    imgs = np.array(cv2.imread(image).shape)
    #print(type(imgs))
    n = len(imgs)
    img = np.ones(imgs)
    val_1 = list(range(1, n - 1, 2))
    val_2 = list(range(0, n - 1, 2))
    print(img)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        axes = (val_1, val_2, [n-1])
    else:
        axes = (val_2, val_1, [n - 1])
    print(type(axes))
    if type(axes) == tuple:
        transposed_axes = np.transpose(img, axes=np.concatenate(axes))
        #print(transposed_axes)
        new_arr_shape = []
        for x in axes:
            new_arr_shape.append(np.prod(img[x]))
        print(type(new_arr_shape))
        print(new_arr_shape)

        for index, x in enumerate(new_arr_shape):
            new_arr_shape[index] = int(x)

        print(new_arr_shape)
        print(len(transposed_axes))

        final_shape = transposed_axes.reshape(new_arr_shape)
        print(type(final_shape))
        print(final_shape)

image = '9.jpg'
image_stack(image)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full output of your code, so we can see what the `print` statements in your code displays?

Comment: @TCArlen I've edited in the results of the `print` statements as into the post as you asked

Comment: If you use `print(transposed_axes.shape)` rather than `print(len(transposed_axes))` you can see that probably `height*width*nchan = 276800`. Furthermore, there's no way you can reshape an image to (1,1,1) so beyond that, I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. Can you explain what it means to "transpose axes values depending on the length of the of the img.shape array."?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, do some work on your own to isolate the piece that you don't understand.

Comment: @PierreD I've already resolved the issue, I realised I was getting the wrong values for the `imgs` variable and been able to fix it